# My app is closing after uncheck item from list

Tags: android

I want to put an alert dialog to checking some items on list. I can choose items but after unchecked it my app is closing. Here is my codes :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Title");

    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(listItem, kontolItem, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
                if(!userCheckedItems.contains(position)){
                    userCheckedItems.add(position);
                }
            } else if(userCheckedItems.contains(position)){
                userCheckedItems.remove(position);
            }
        }
    });
```

logcat error :

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1 at
>   java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:503) at
>   com.kaydeniz.ihaleajandasi2.IhaleKriterleriSecDialogFragment$3.onClick(IhaleKriterleriSecDialogFragment.java:118)

There is problem on "`userCheckedItems.remove(position);`", because this is writing on the logcat. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Post logcat output

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:503)
        at com.kaydeniz.ihaleajandasi2.IhaleKriterleriSecDialogFragment$3.onClick(IhaleKriterleriSecDialogFragment.java:118)

Comment: This problem occurs for example when: let us suppose you clicked on position = 2 (not already found) then 2 gets added to userCheckedItems at index 0. Clicked another item let say position = 5  (not already found) then 5 gets added to userCheckeditems at index 1. Suppose now you decided to uncheck element at position = 5 from the list, then you are trying to remove item 5 from index (position in your case) 5 inside userCheckedItems which doesn't exist, because currently userCheckedItems has only two elements (indices 0 and 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List api's remove function overloaded for index and object. And your userCheckedItems list hold integers so when you call remove, it try to remove it by index and causing error. To prevent confusion you can check your item index and remove it by index. To figure out your item index you can call indexOf function. To fix your crash you can do like :

```
else if(userCheckedItems.contains(p)){
       int indexOfItem = userCheckedItems.indexOf(p);
       userCheckedItems.remove(indexOfItem);
  }
```

---

---